# retrieve servlet variable via jstl

Tags: jsp, jstl

i have an arraylist of strings in my servlet which im passing forwarding using this:

```
//in servlet

ArrayList<String> output = new ArrayList<String>();
//populate arraylist with values here

//forward the string
request.setAttribute("myData ", output);
request.getRequestDispatcher("Home.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

i know that i can access this in scriplet notation:

```
ArrayList<String> myData = (ArrayList<String>)request.getAttribute("myData");
```

how do i access this in jstl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `<c:forEach />` to iterate the list - [JSTL](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnakh.html#bnakk) reference doc.

```
<c:forEach var="name" items="${myData}">
   <br/>${name}
</c:forEach>
```